# matriz antisimetrica estilo de programación

Tags: c++, loops, matrices

Tengo un ejercicio de matrices en donde debo comprobar si una matriz es antisimétrica :

> Impleméntese  el  método  `bool   matrix_t<int>::is_antisymmetric(void)`, el  cual    devuelve    verdadero   si  la  relación    descrita    en  la   matriz  es  antisimétrica,  o   falso   en  caso    contrario.  Es 
>   decir,     devuelve    verdadero  si   para    toda par `(i,j)` si     existe  el 
>   par    `(j,i)` entonces   `i  =   j`.

para contextualizar, esta es la clase que me dan:

```
template <class T> class matrix_t
{
private:
 int m_;
 int n_;

 T* v_;
public:
 matrix_t(void);
 matrix_t(int m, int n);
 ~matrix_t(void);

 void resize(int m, int n);
 T& get_set (int i, int j);
 T get (int i, int j) const;
 int get_m(void) const;
 int get_n(void) const;
private:
 int pos(int i, int j) const;
};
```

Así es como hice el ejercicio, paradójicamente me compiló pero sospecho que la ejecución no es la yo deseo.

```
bool<int>:: is_antisymmetric(void){

 bool antisymmetric = false;

 for (int i=2; i<= m_ && (antisymmetric == false); i++){
  for (int j=1; j<= i-1 && (antisymmetric == false); j++){
    if (get(i,j) != get(j,i)){
     antisymmetric=true;
    }
   }
  }
 return antisymmetric;
}
```

Así es como está planteado el ejercicio resuelto

```
bool is_anti_symmetric(void)
{ bool is_asym = true;
  int  i       = 2;

  while ((is_asym == true) && (i <= get_m())) {
    int j = 1;
    while ((is_asym == true) && (j <= i - 1)) {
      if ((get(i,j) == 1) && (get(j,i) == 1))
        is_asym = false;
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return is_asym;
}
```

**¿Cuál es el fallo de planteo de mi ejercicio y del que no me doy cuenta?**

Otra duda: no entiendo esta línea de código

```
if ((get(i,j) == 1) && (get(j,i) == 1))
```

Comment: "sospecho que la ejecución no es la que yo deseo" ¿y por que no lo pruebas? Es parte del aprender a programar.

Comment: vuelve a leer la pregunta mas despacio y sin prisa

Comment: amigo tu tienes un serio problema con la buena practica del codigo, tienes q usar nombres de variables mas legibles y poner muchos comentarios si quieres que tu codigo se entienda facilmente, con esos nombres de variables, creo que hasta tu te confundes. Segundo, para los constructores y destructores no nesesitas poner `(void)` es muy redundante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, es redundante usar variables `m` y `n` para definir el numero de filas y columnas de la matriz porque si solo queremos saber si es *simetrica* tiene que ser *obligatoriamente* una matriz *cuadrada*.
Asi que esta demas definir un constructor para filas y columnas, por eso solo usa una misma variable para el constructor, si el ejercicio resuelto las usa, pues que tonto el que lo hizo, se esta complicando la vida por cosas sencillas.

No voy a ponerte la solucion a tu tarea, no quiero quitarte la sorpresa :)
Pero si te voy a ayudar a entender que es lo que pasa con las matrices simetricas.

Resulta que con las matrices simetricas tienes q mirar a una matriz cuadrada, el truco es simplemente ver si *tiene espejo*, pero como hacemos para que una computadora se de cuenta de eso? Facil... solo cambiale el orden de los recorredores(tambien se les dice iteradores).

Digamos que tienes ya implementada una matriz...

```
// retorna falso si no es simetrica, en caso de que si lo sea, retorna verdadero
bool acaso_es_simetrica(int &matriz) const {
    //obviamos el caso en que i sea igual a j, o sea no nos interesa la diagonal
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) { 
            if (matriz[i][j] != matriz[j][i]) return false;
            //comprobamos si todos los elementos que no esten en la diagonal
            //son exactamente iguales
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Tienes que obviar la diagonal de una matriz no importa de que tamaño sea, porque las matrices diagonales:

- Son matrices cuadradas.
- No les interesa que elementos haya en la diagonal.
- Los elementos de el triangulo superior e inferior deben ser iguales.

Es por eso que tu linea `if ((get(i,j) == 1) && (get(j,i) == 1))` comprueba esto mismo, el metodo `get()` retorna Verdadero o Falso, que en Binarios es 1 o 0.
Si es que existe retorna Verdadero que en Binarios es 1 entonces el numero esta presente y asi sigue buscando...
En esa linea dice:
Si el elemento de la matriz ubicado en (i, j) es exactamente igual a el elemento de la misma matriz ubicado en (j, i) entonces haz tal cosa...